# What's the point of $validators and $setValidity?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I think I'm missing something with `$validators` and `$setValidity` (which I understand, do the exact same thing so you don't need both - please correct me if I'm wrong). Whether I have the `$validators` statement in there or not, I get the ng-invalid class added to the input form, which is adding a red border around the input. So why do I need the `$validators`? I am trying to set the parent form to be invalid if a user does not select a row from the dropdownnin the directive template. I don't want to show any error messages or anything, I just want to add the invalid class and red border based on if a row in the dropdown was selected.

Should I be using `$validators` or `$setValidity`? Do I need both `$validator` and `$setValidity` like I have below? Also, does `$setValidity` required `ngModelCtrl` or not? I get undefined for `setValidity` if it is not inside the `$validators` function. Any help is appreciated.

If I want to make the parent form invalid as a whole if no selection is made and I am getting ng-invalid class when I touch and then blur if no selection is made without `$validators` and `$setValidity`, then why do I need the `$validators` and `$setValidity`??

### index.html

```
   <form name="myForm">
      <validator 
         rows="[{name:'tom', city:'san fran', state: 'mn', zip: 34212},
               {name: 'joe', city:'san fran', state: 'mn', zip: 45675}]"
         ng-required="true"
         ng-model="hey">
      </validator>
  </form>
```

### validate.js - DDO

```
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: {
      ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel',
      formCtrl: '?^form'
   },
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'view.html',
      scope: {},
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: {
         rows: '=',
         onSelected: '&?', //passsed selected row outside component
         typedText: '&?', //text typed into input passed outside so 
                          //developer can create a custom filter,
                          //overriding the auto
         textFiltered: '@?', //text return from the custom filter
         ngRequired: "=?" //default false, when set to true the component
             //needs to validate that something was selected on blur.
             //The selection is not put into the input element all the
             //time so it can't validate based on whether or not
             //something is in the input element itself. 
             //I need to validate inside the controller where I can see
             //if 'this.ngModel' (selectedRow - not passed through scope)
             //is undefined or not.
        },
         controller: 'validatorController'
  };
```

.

```
   function validatorController () {
         var ctrl = this;
         var rowWasSelected = false;
         var input = ctrl.formCtrl.inputField; 

         //called via ng-click on the dropdown row
         //if this is called a row was selected
         ctrl.rowSelected = function (row){
             rowWasSelected = true;
         }

         //called via ng-blur of the input element
         ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$validators.invalidInput = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
               return rowWasSelected;
           }


         ctrl.$onInit = $onInit; //angular will execute this after 
             //all conrollers have been initialized, only safe to use
             //bound values (through bindToController) in 
             //the $onInit function.

             //i understand this need to be there with Angular 1.5 
             //using ngModel in the controller
             //but I really only need to validate on ng-blur of the input
        function $onInit() {
              ctrl.validateInput();
            }
           }
         };
      }
```

### view.html - template for directive

```
   <div class="dropdown" ng-class="{'open' : ctrl.isOpen}">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputField"
               placeholder="select" ng-click="ctrl.openDropdown()"
               ng-blur="ctrl.validateInput()" 
               ng-model="ctrl.currentRow.name"
               ng-required="ctrl.ngRequired">
       </div>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="row in ctrl.rows"
          ng-click="ctrl.onSelectedLocal(row)">
             {{row.name}}
      </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

I must be getting the invalid class regardless of the `$validators` function I have because it is adding the `ng-invalid` class whether its there or not??

Comment: If you're not sure why something is invalid, just print the `$error` object in your HTML: `{{myForm.inputField.$error | json}}`. For example, this could show that perhaps the it is the `required` validation that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

> ### `$setValidity(validationErrorKey, isValid);`
>
> Change the validity state, and notify the form.
>
> This method can be called within `$parsers/$formatters` or a custom validation implementation. However, in most cases it should be sufficient to use the `ngModel.$validators` and `ngModel.$asyncValidators` collections which will call `$setValidity` automatically.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setValidity)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response George. I've read the docs but its not making sense to me why I would be getting the ng-invalid class on the input. If I'm able to use the invalid class that means the input must be invalid, which would make the form invalid as well..is that correct? Even when its a directive inside the form? I know parsers/formatters are a way to manipulate the data traveling back and forth from view to model and vice versa but I'm not really doing any of that in this case. I adjusted my initial post, shouldn't that validate function be adding the invalid class on page load? Thanks